# Map function, set index from and index to

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-pdf

Is it possible set index of function/method map()?
Do not render all cars, but cars e.g. from id 2 to id 4.
Example with 5 cars and render with component `<View>` and `<Text>` from library "@react-pdf/renderer": "2.3.0".

```
{
  "cars": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "brand": "Toyota",
      "type": "Corolla",
      "color": "white"
    },
    {
      "id": "1",
      "brand": "Mazda",
      "type": "CX-30",
      "color": "red"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "brand": "Honda",
      "type": "Civic",
      "color": "brown"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "brand": "Audi",
      "type": "A6",
      "color": "black"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "brand": "Mercedes",
      "type": "GLC",
      "color": "grey"
    }
  ],
  "total": 5
}

{data?.cars.map((car: any, index: number) => {
  return (
    <View 
      key={index}
    >
      <Text>{index + 1}</Text>
      <Text>{car.brand || ""}</Text>
      <Text>{car.type || ""}</Text>
      <Text>{car.color || ""}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

With for loop is not works.

```
{(() => {
  return (
    for (let j = 2; j < 5; j++) {  // <--- Unreachable code
      <View 
        key={j}
      >
        <Text>{j + 1}</Text>
        <Text>{car.brand || ""}</Text>
        <Text>{car.type || ""}</Text>
        <Text>{car.color || ""}</Text>
      </View>
    }
  )
})()}
```

I use typescript and reactjs 17.0.2.

Comment: Try to avoid using `for..in` loops in React, use `Array.prototype.map/reduce/forEach` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `slice` method, `data?.cars.slice(2).map` to slice the array from index 3 ( the element whose has id = 2 ) to the rest of the array ( as the element whose id = 4 is the last element in the array ).

```
{data?.cars.slice(2).map((car: any, index: number) => {
  return (
    <View 
      key={index}
    >
      <Text>{car?.brand : ""}</Text>
      <Text>{car?.type : ""}</Text>
      <Text>{car?.color : ""}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Nice solution. `{data?.cars.slice(2, 4).map((car: any, index: number)` But it changed index of items. I use for example 1000 items and I need paginate after e.g. 5 items.
[1.pdf page: items from 0-5.],[2.pdf page: items from 5-10.],...,[n.pdf page: items from 995-1000.]

Comment: `car?.brand` no need for optional chaining as `car` is guaranteed to exist and you're only accessing one level deep.

Comment: @Elo, so set a state for the lastIndex, slice from that index, and update the lastIndex on the page change.

Comment: @pilchard, I didn't focus on the text syntax, as I was focusing on the main question requirement, but I think it's totally wrong syntax `{car?.brand : ""}` it should be `{car.brand || ""}`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I repaired it in code to `{car?.brand ? car.brand : ""}`

Comment: Never mind, but just `{car.brand || ""}` will do the same behavior with just one check, but `{car?.brand ? car.brand : ""}` will check falsy value twice, one on the `car` and the second on the `car.brand` and `car` will not be undefined except if there are `undefined` elements in the array.

Comment: Thank you for explain it. I repaired it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of doing this:

1. Use a [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
{data?.cars.filter(car => parseInt(car.id) >= 2 && parseInt(car.id) <= 4).map((car: any, index: number) => {
  return (
    <View 
      key={index}
    >
      <Text>{car?.brand : ""}</Text>
      <Text>{car?.type : ""}</Text>
      <Text>{car?.color : ""}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

2. You use a ternary operator (conditional rendering) in the map:

```
{data?.cars.map((car: any, index: number) => {
  return (parseInt(car.index) >= 2 && parseInt(car.index) <= 4) ? (
    <View 
      key={index}
    >
      <Text>{car?.brand : ""}</Text>
      <Text>{car?.type : ""}</Text>
      <Text>{car?.color : ""}</Text>
    </View>
  ) : </>
}
```

Note: I would use `card.index` as `key` and not the index in the array. Something like this:

```
.map(car: any => {
  return (
    <View 
      key={car.index}
    >
      <Text>{car?.brand : ""}</Text>
      <Text>{car?.type : ""}</Text>
      <Text>{car?.color : ""}</Text>
    </View>
  )
```

Comment: Sorry man, but `filter()` return nothing. And also ternary operator also return nothing (after : </> will throw an error). In contrast to slice(2, 4) works. When I try to use `key={car.index}`, `<Text>{car.index + 1}</Text>` on frontend it's NaN. I use uuid as id. Maybe this is the problem? But why `slice()` works?

Comment: @Elo You are right, my bad. Didn't notice the ids are strings, I've added parseInt. But if you're ids are uuid then parseInt won't work either. Slice doesn't rely on the ids, but on the index in the array. Depending on your use case that may be a valid option.